# How do I call a class from another class(not inheritance) in Java?

Tags: java, class

I can't remember what it's called when another class's method in java for example in a main class you call the scanner class to scan in user input?

Comment: eh, a method/operation invocation?

Answer (score 2):

I think you're looking for the names of associations like aggregation and composition.
The terms are used to describe [Releationships](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_diagram#Instance_Level_Relationships) in UML

Comment: Is this the terminology to be used in UML diagramming?

Comment: Yes - I will add references as links

Answer (score 1):

If the scan method is an instance (object) method (not static), it would be something like this

```
Scanner s = new Scanner();
s.scan();
```

If scan is static (a class method), then

```
Scanner.scan();
```

Edit: The name of the relationship is Dependency in UML.  You say that Main depends on Scanner or Main uses-a Scanner.  I made this UML slideshow and cheatsheet:

http://www.loufranco.com/blog/files/UMLCheatsheet.html

If you have a Scanner member in the main class, then this is usually called has-a, composition, or an association.

Comment: That's not what I'm after, I'm looking for what the name of the relationship would be between two classes of the example I provided.

Comment: It's called Uses-a or depends-on in UML.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not clear.

but maybe the following example will help:

```
class Scanner{
  public void scan(){}
}

//use inheritance
class SubScanner extends Scanner{
  public void scan(){}       //overriding
  public void scan(int i){}  //overloading
}

//use aggreagation
class MainClass{
  private final Scanner scanner;
  MainClass(Scanner scanner){
    this.scanner = scanner;
  }
  public void scan(){ 
    scanner.scan();         //delegation call
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a table of many UML relationships

http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/rtnlhelp/v6r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.xtools.modeler.doc/topics/rreltyp.html